# ¿Como insertar datos a un ArrayList en una posicion especifica?

Tags: arraylist

Soy nuevo en esto de los arraylist y me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de insertar en una posicion dada por el usuario
No se si al insertar se deben recorrer en una posicion los que estan delante de el

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! un arraylist en que lenguaje? podrias ser mas especifio? que intentaste? usa el boton [edit] y agrega la informacion a la pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para ayudarte mejor por favor indícanos qué lenguaje de programación usas (debes poner a la pregunta la etiqueta de ese lenguaje), qué código estás implementanto y qué error tienes específicamente. Gracias.

Comment: Si bien `ArrayList` puede identificarse para los entendidos como `Java` (`no JS`) sería oportuno indicar el lenguaje de programación con una etiqueta a fin de facilitar la identificación de esta pregunta aquí en **stackoverflow**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando insertas un elemento en un ArrayList en una posición específica debes declarar el índice. Para que se entienda te daré el siguiente ejemplo:

```
ArrayList<String> nombre = new ArrayList<String>();
//Añadir Elementos a un ArrayList
nombre.add("Victor");
nombre.add("Luis");
nombre.add("Elena");
```

con el código anterior se tienen los siguientes índices:

```
[0] => "Victor"
[1] => "Luis"
[2] => "Elena"
```

Pero si quieres poner un nombre extra en un índice específico debes declarar ese índice de la siguiente manera:

```
nombre.add(1, "Andres");
```

O sea que agregamos el nombre Andres con el índice 1, por lo que quedará de la siguiente manera:

```
[0] => "Victor"
[1] => "Andres"
[2] => "Luis"
[3] => "Elena"
```

Como puedes ver al ingresar un elemento en un ArrayList en una posición específica declarando el índice de la posición, los demás elementos automáticamente se desplazarán.

Saludos!!

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigo :) desconocía que el Arraylist al añadir en una posición especifica recorría automáticamente los elementos que se encuentran delante del elemento agregado